# is there a way to solve higher power nonlinear equations using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

im new to python and sympy , but I'm trying to use sympy to solve equations of  high powers which i cannot manually do .The code I'm using worked for lower powers but for this specific equation ,the code runs but the output is  an empty list [].Is there a way to fix this ?
I tried running it without setting y to be positive and the result was the same.
Is there a way to fix this ?

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
y = Symbol('y',positive = True)
q = 45
b = 5
x = 2
s = 0.001
n = 0.015
eq = Eq (q,(1/n)*(((y*(b + x*y))/( b + 2*y*sqrt(1 + x**2)))**(2/3))*(sqrt(s))*(y*(b + x*y)))
m  = solve(eq,y)
pprint(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nsolve` but you would have to provide an initial guess. For example:

```py
# solve eq for y, with an initial guess of y=2
nsolve(eq, y, 2)
# out: 2.0002640101498
```

Since this is a relatively easy equation, you can use `plot` to find a proper initial guess:

```
plot(eq.rewrite(Add))
```

Comment: may you guide me on how to use the plot function to obtain the initial guess

Comment: Just look at the plot and see where the line crosses the x axis